# Passing Data from View to Model in MVC in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Is it possible to pass data from view to model in mvc? this question was asked in interview.Please anyone give me right answer.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should plan on reading some materials on how MVC architecture works. You have used the term model and view without understanding what it exactly is. Overview on ASP.net MVC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To pass data to controller through model you should wrap all the inputs (checkboxes, textboxes, radio etc.) with `<form ...>` tag. You could do it using HTML tag or with help of ASP.NET MVC helper `@Html.BeginForm(...)`. Once you submit your form, all the input data will be sent to a controller action and mapped to a targeted model. Please see an example:

### Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

### View:

```
@model UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Events"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

### Controller:

```
public class EventsController: Controller
{
   public ActionResult Search(UserModel model)
   {
      //do something

      return View(); //return "Search" view to the user
      //return View(model); //You can also return view with the model to the user
      //return View("SpecificView"); //You can specify a concrete view name as well 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, we do not pass any information from view to model directly, both the view and model are different module. we can pass data, value or any information from view to model via controller.